# Moving rows of table in Chrome (table gets corrupt)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html-table

We are working on a data grid and found out that during moving rows (TR) in a table (TABLE) with jQuery the table may get corrupt under Chrome (Firefox and Opera works great). In those cases floated DIVs inside TDs do not obey the float anymore or in another case there are extra columns even the HTML structure is absolutely ok. I couldn't generate a clean and easy test case yet, but just want to ask if there is a known problem with that in Chrome.

It really seems buggy as detaching the whole table and reattaching it again (without changing something else) does solve the problem and the table layout is correct again.

Comment: I doubt anybody will be able to help you if you do not post some of the code involved with your pages.

Comment: I guess you are right ... it is so hard to reproduce it with a simple snippet that I hoped it is a well known problem. But I will try to make a good test case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var firstRow = document.getElementById('<%=tblColumn.ClientID %>').rows[index]; 
                var secondRow = document.getElementById('<%=tblColumn.ClientID %>').rows[index+1];              
                firstRow.parentNode.insertBefore(secondRow, firstRow);
```

try this code for chrome